Incorrect calculation of a math expression using sin and cos in C?
Why does this simple program
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int res = (int)(-1 * sin(M_PI/2) + 1 * cos(M_PI/2));
    printf("-1 * %f + 1 * %f = %d\n", sin(M_PI/2), cos(M_PI/2), res);
    return 0;
}

give the following incorrect output?
-1 * 1.000000 + 1 * 0.000000 = 0


What is the expected output?

@Someprogrammerdude
-1

The reason it fails is that you have made res an int and on the compiler that you happen to use sin(M_PI/2) evaluates to 1-machine_eps. I suspect that if you compiled it with full optimisation it will actually work as intended since then the answer can be computed at compile time and typically compile time computation of constant values can be more accurate than that of runtime libraires. Few decent optimisers don't know that sin(M_PI/2) == 1 and substitute accordingly. Which compiler was it? Change %f to %g24.16 to see what is really going on.

I deleted my comment because the provided answer is way more detailled. Casting to integer just truncates. If you want to round, you must use round function or similar.

@MartinBrown I used gcc -g -Wall -Wextra stack_overflow.c -lm -o stack_overflow

For one thing, despite appearances, you did not actually take the sine or cosine of exactly pi/2. See this question and maybe also this question.

If you print more significant digits:
double res = -1 * sin(M_PI/2) + 1 * cos(M_PI/2);
printf("-1 * %.17f + 1 * %.17f = %.17f\n", sin(M_PI/2), cos(M_PI/2), res);

You'll see the problem:
-1 * 1.00000000000000000 + 1 * 0.00000000000000006 = -0.99999999999999989

The inexact nature of floating point is in this case giving a result for the call to cos that is not exactly 0.  So your final result is slightly greater than -1, and converting that value to a int truncates the value toward 0, giving 0 as a result.

Yes, thanks, I just didn't expect the conversion to not round the number to the nearest value.

OT: Casting to double isn't needed

@Fyodor You can use the round function to round to the nearest integer (with halfway cases rounded away from zero).

On most systems cos actually computes the closest possible result quite accurately (for not too large inputs). The main problem is that M_PI is not (and can not be) exactly п, thus cos(M_PI/2) != 0. If you have C23 consider using cospi.

cos(M_PI/2) is not expected to be 0.
M_PI is not π.
M_PI, sometimes called machine pi, is a floating point value near π, but not exactly π.  π is a transcendental number and not representable as a rational number.  All finite floating point numbers are rational.
The value of cosine(π/2) from a math sense is 0.0, yet since cos(M_PI/2) is only somewhat near zero,  being a bit above or below 0.0, -1 * sin(M_PI/2) + 1 * cos(M_PI/2) can be a bit above, equal or below -1.  When the sum is like -0.999..., (int)(-0.999...) is 0.
The graph at sin, cos, tan and rounding error may help.
